# Will I be able to fetch a Data Analyst job if I learn everything in this image?

Tags: machine-learning, bigdata, databases, data-analysis

India

Asking such a question because I am interested learn everything myself and I am confused about what to read. 
And I am interested by reading books, will that suffice? or should I compulsorily attend a course and get certificate(because some say I might require certificate compulsorily)??
Please can somebody throw some light on this.(Please do if you are an Indian based Data Analyst or Data Scientist)
Thank you.

**I AM A COMMERCE GRADUATE AND INTERESTED IN DATA SCIENCE

[image: Credits: nirvacana.com ; Swami Chandrasekharan]

Comment: If you learn everything in the image, you will be a highly skilled specialist (that will take years), but for a job you usually also need a certificate that proves that you learned it (a.k.a degree/ course). From your question, I got a feeling that you are still far from the required knowledge and skills.

Comment: For academy, of course. But for a job, there is more to go than learning; you need to implement complete projects and you need to be able to demonstrate complete applications of what you know. Learn and constantly apply (try) what you have learned to some solid work by yourself. Do not stress yourself with should I learn this or this, constantly learn, do, apply, search, communicate. You will know what to do and learn by yourself at some point. All those worked out very well for my Data Science career. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think someone can learn about everything in the image and be good at all of them. Especially when you get out of school !

You need to master:

- Fundamentals
- Statistics
- Programming
- Machine Learning
- Visualization

The rest depends on what you want to specialize into.